# ¿Cuál es el origen de la palabra "emputarse"?

Tags: etimología, coloquialismos, colombia

En Colombia este verbo significa "enojarse demasiado". Buscando en el DLE se puede encontrar su significado:

> **[emputarse](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Etsj4Ww)**
>
> De en- y puta.
>
> 1. prnl. malson. coloq. El Salv., Hond. y Méx. encolerizarse.

Como se ve en la entrada, existe una relación con *puta*, cuya entrada en el DLE es:

> **[puto, ta](http://dle.rae.es/?id=UjqH8h6)**
>
> Quizá del lat. vulg. *puttus*, var. del lat. *putus* 'niño'.
>
> 1. adj. malson. U. como calificación denigratoria. *Me quedé en la puta calle.*
> 2. adj. malson. U. c. antífrasis, para ponderar. *Ha vuelto a ganar. ¡Qué puta suerte tiene!*
> 3. adj. malson. U. para enfatizar la ausencia o la escasez de algo. *No tengo un puto duro.*
> 4. m. y f. malson. prostituto.
> 5. m. malson. sodomita (que practica la sodomía).

No logro asociar los dos términos. ¿Existe alguna razón histórica para el origen de esta palabra?

Comment: ¿Es posible que más que del significado de "puta" venga de su uso como interjección? En el *Diccionario de americanismos* vienen muchos usos de "[¡puta!](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=puta)" y derivados ("¡como putas!", "¿en dónde putas?") para expresar sorpresa, enfado y otros. Por lo que es posible que la etimología de "emputarse" simplemente se refiera a una persona que empieza a decir "¡puta!" repetidamente y con enfado.

Comment: Eso tiene bastante sentido. Yo lo estaba interpretando más por el lado de la prostitución.

Comment: Es que hay una diferencia importante entre ser y estar. Ser puto/a tiene que ver con lo de la prostitución que mencionas, pero **estar puto/a** si tienen que ver con enojo, rabia, cólera, por lo que como dice @Charlie está relacionado con la interjección y no con el sustantivo. ¿El origen? Sabrá el **tas :-)

Comment: Análogamente tienes http://dle.rae.es/?id=EwSoyd5 **encabronar**; de *en-* y *cabrón* 1. tr. malson. coloq. Enojar, enfadar. U. t. c. prnl.

Comment: En América del Sur decimos [**emputecer(se)**](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=emputecer)

Comment: @Rodrigo En Argentina se usa la segunda acepción ("Complicarse una situación") y ésa no coincide con la de la versión colombiana.

Answer (score 2):

Sin ningún rigor etimológico, diré que en México, la palabra usada es 'emputecerse', que se forma con el prefijo em- y el reflexivo de 'putear' que frecuentemente se refiere a dar una golpiza.

Uno que se emputece frecuentemente comienza a aventar y romper cosas.

El DLE dice de em-:

> en-
>   Tb. em- ante b o p. Del lat. in-.
>   1. pref. Interviene, sin significación precisa, en la formación de algunos derivados. Empalizar, embrutecer, encapado.